# Can't save syntax colouring in Spyder

Tags: colors, spyder

Downloaded Spyder yesterday with Anaconda like everyone else.
I went preferences - syntax colouring - create new - (changing colors) - save,
then the whole preference window just disappears.
It is the same when I tried to edit existing scheme.

I tried only changing bold, and click save without changing any,
then the whole window doesn't disappear.

Please help me. I want my coloring.

Comment: What do you mean by: "then the whole window doesn't disappear." ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't disappear. it just goes below other windows.